# How to import "manually" configurations from another hard drive?

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome

I have another hard drive with Ubuntu upgrading that crashed (upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04 was an unrecoverable mistake).

I've bought another hard drive, re-installed Ubuntu 10.04 (because don't ask me why but 12.04 doesn't detect properly network) and now that all works, I'd like to import "manually" what was setup in Firefox on the other hard drive. I've found a lot of information on google about how to export then import, but not how to do this "manually".

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried:

```
~/.mozilla # cp -R /mnt/crappyubuntu12/home/olivier/.mozilla/firefox .
```

But it doesn't work (at all)

Same question for Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firefox, you can just copy your profile directory from the failed harddrive to the new harddrive (Similar path) (Try keeping the same/newer Firefox version in target OS). It should work without modifications. It works even from Windows to Ubuntu. Not sure about chrome.

EDIT: As Fayaz pointed out, in case you have already launched Firefox once before, it would have auto created a default profile. In that case, either delete that profile and then copy over the profile from the old drive or using Firefox Profile Manager (Firefox /p), set the copied profile as default.

Comment: What I tried worked (and it's your solution actually), but it needed not only close, but **reboot**.